# Knockoutjs dynamically created tags not getting Bootstrap styles

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am using knockoutjs inside of a Bootstrap enabled app. Everything works fine on page load. However I have a scenario where I am using an html template's content to dynamically copy and paste into my page after initial load. This content does not get the bootstrap styles at all as its copied into the page from a different html file.

Its pretty obvious why this is happening, obviously bootstrap has completed what it needed to do during initial page load. However I'd like to know if there's any way around this situation. For example is there a call in bootstrap.js that will refresh the styling on the page at the end of the dynamic render, like a callback of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

This is a clear case for creating a knockout [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) for the bootstrap functionality in question. This will ensure they are binded with their correct bootstrap events etc as knockout generates them.

It's nice to learn how to make them as you can extend it for other things too but if you don't have time and need quick results, like anything else in out industry this dude has had a go at making most [bootstrap stuff in custom binding handler format](http://billpull.github.io/knockout-bootstrap/)